# highchart data from mysql using ajax

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax, database, highcharts

I want to create a line chart that shows the data from my database live.

I put new data into my database about every 100 microseconds.

I use ajax to check for new data.

this is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickPixelInterval: 150,
            maxZoom: 20 * 1000
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Random data',
            data: []
        }]
    });

    $('#button').click(function() {
        $.get('data.php', function(data) {
        chart.series[0].setData(data);
        });
    });
});
</script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 400px"></div>
    <button id="button">Set new data</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

the data.php returns the following:

```
[
[Date.UTC(0000, 00, 00, 11, 11, 47, 7), 144],
[Date.UTC(0000, 00, 00, 11, 11, 47, 17), 143],
[Date.UTC(0000, 00, 00, 11, 11, 47, 29), 142],
[Date.UTC(0000, 00, 00, 11, 11, 47, 39), 141],
]
```

But it doesn't show up in my chart.

Can you help me make this work?

Answer (score 0):

It works. I dont know what issues you are facing.
But thing that i see is the time interval between your data is in milliseconds and you have provided larger tick interval.

I removed tick interval (so that highcharts plots them automatically) as well maxzoomperiod.

Check it here. http://jsfiddle.net/pLUza/

**PS:** I Just embedded data to Data field in Series option. But any how the result will remain same when you use AJAX.